# SQL to append records

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables tbl1 and tbl2. Consider tbl2 as the main set and tbl1 has been derived from other sources but will essentially now be a subset of tbl2.

**tbl1**

| cd | productcd | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 2 | AB |
| 1 | 3 | A |
| 2 | 3 | AB |
| 2 | 4 | AC |
| 3 | 1 | A |

**tbl2**

| cd | productcd | type | priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | AB | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | A | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | AB | 4 |
| 1 | 5 | AC | 7 |
| 2 | 1 | A | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | AB | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | AC | 8 |
| 2 | 7 | HV | 10 |
| 3 | 1 | A | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | AC | 3 |
| 3 | 7 | BC | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | E | 9 |
| 3 | 5 | T | 11 |

How do I retrieve for each group of CD limit each group to only 4 records?
So the final o/p has to be all the records of tbl1 and missing records ( max limit of 4) will be populated from tbl2

**Final o/p being**

| cd | productcd | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 2 | AB |
| 1 | 3 | A |
| 1 | 4 | AB |
| 2 | 3 | AB |
| 2 | 4 | AC |
| 2 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 7 | HV |
| 3 | 1 | A |
| 3 | 2 | AC |
| 3 | 7 | BC |
| 3 | 4 | E |

Comment: What's your SQL query? You may be able to use some sort of `UNION`

Comment: Where there are more than 4, what's your logic for determining *which* 4?

Comment: What is your MySql version?

Comment: @Martin from multiple file and all I have now these two tables tbl1 and tbl2. Tried using union but then how do I limit to not more than 4?

Comment: @Stu every record has a priority which i missed displaying in the table, its sorted on that in above tbl2

Comment: @Serg am on mysql 8

Comment: What is the purpose of tbl1 with reference to the desired results?

Comment: @Stu All records in tbl1 needs to be considered in the limit of 4 before picking up records from tbl2.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the *missing priority* information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can use `row_number` to select and order the required rows for each `cd` and use `exists` to prioritise rows from `tbl1`

```
with t as (
  select *, 
    Row_Number() over(
        partition by cd 
        order by 
            case when exists (
                    select * from tbl1 where tbl1.cd=tbl2.cd and tbl1.productcd=tbl2.productcd
                ) then 0 else 1 
            end, priority) rn
  from tbl2
)
select cd, productcd, type
from t
where rn<=4
```

See [Working DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6617ce16123818d2b59b07808239b9e4)